# Would you make marking as answer easier to find?

Tags: feature-request, user-interface

The Mark as Answer check is too subtle for me. I tend to tune out things in gray and can be icon-blind. After reading an answer, my eyes are at the bottom of the answer.

I imagine that frequent askers in this network remember about the checkmark, but I ask only a few times a year. Someone just answered my question, I looked for a place to mark it answered, and could not find it, so just replied that they answered the question. When they replied that I needed to mark the question as answered, I looked again and still could not find it. I literally did not notice the checkmark. I had to Google how to accomplish that.

It would be better if there were a link with the words "mark as answer" at the bottom of each answer next to the "share" link. That's where I would have expected to see it.

It's fine if the checkmark remains, but it would be much better if there were also a text link together with the other text links.

Would you please consider this improvement?

Comment: It's definitely possible, given that here on MSE it's in a circle just like the vote buttons.

Comment: +1 yes it would be great especially for new users who usually don't go out of their way to look for such an option. It would also be great to have a pop up saying something like "if this answers your question, please *accept* it here" with an arrow or something.

Comment: *sigh* I am not a fan of pop-ups. I find them disruptive.

Comment: @CharlesBelov Agreed.  Sadly that popup already exists.

Comment: @Servy Oh I didn't know that! I use the SE app and so I never encountered the popup. I was just judging by the amount of times that an OP would just leave a comment on my answer saying *thank you that worked so well* instead of accepting the answer

Comment: This kind of thing certainly would have helped this person: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/326139/how-to-use-the-title-command-json-in-1-13/326140#comment464790_326140